# Python- Como melhor armazenar informações (data) cadastrais geradas por input?

Tags: banco-de-dados, json, python-3.x

Tenho usado write ("with open" "write") para sobrescrever e/ou adicionar data(nomes pessoais, endereço,telefone) nos scripts.py, e tem dado certo, mas se eu não tomar cuidado fica uma bagunça,tanto porque os scripts que armazenam data ficam enormes, como por ter que importa-los,criando uma rede de scripts comunicáveis que exige cuidado ao importar. Isso é chato e provavelmente desnecessário. Bibliotecas como Json seriam uma alternativa melhor ? Se sim, qual a mais indicada para esse propósito ( informações cadastrais) ? Parecem haver muitas ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Opção Banco de dados

Talvez o melhor pra você seja usar um banco de dados. Pode ser o SQLite mesmo, que já vem com Python. Agora banco de dados não é uma fórmula mágica.

É legal por que permite que você leia ou escreva cada registro individualmente no disco, sabendo que quando faz uma operação de atualização os dados já ficam salvos e seguros. Por outro lado, exige que você entenda toda uma linguagem e conceitos diferentes, - o SQL - mesmo que você não vá usar SQL direto, há bibliotecas Python que são adaptadores Objeto-Relacional, como o SQLAlchemy - você terá que entender de orientação a objetos e uso de classes e instâncias, alguns detalhes do SQLAlchemy, e ele gera os comandos de SQL pra você (por isso pode só "entender" SQL e não necessariamente "aprender"). Mas mesmo assim é bastante coisa para um programa simples;

Se você usar o sqlite, que vem junto com o Python, não é necessário configurar ou instalar um banco de dados externo, como o MariaDB ou o PostgreSQL

## Opção arquivos JSON

Se o número de cadastros for pequeno - por exemplo, menos que 2000, dá para manter os dados em memória enquanto o programa estiver rodando, e cada vez que o programa terminar, ou  a cada x minutos, salvar todos os dados - e você pode usar Json pra isso sim.

A vantagem é que seus dados já ficam num formato que e usável diretamente por outras tecnologias, ou editáveis diretamente num editor de textos. O que você tem que aprender para usar é bem simples.

A maior desvantagem talvez seja que JSON tem uns poucos tipos de dados primitivos, e se seus registros tiverem objetos como datas, timestamps, imagens, conjuntos, vai ter que tratar esses dados de forma especial.

## Arquivos Pickle

Python tem um pacote chamado "pickle" na biblioteca padrão - ele pode transformar praticamente qualquer objeto Python em uma sequência de bytes, que pode ser armazenada em um arquivo, e recuperar os objetos a partir daí. O seu programa fica muito pareceido com a abordagem necessária para o JSON: é mais fácil ler e escrever todos os registros de uma só vez, e trabalhar com os dados em memória, etc... a maior diferença é que o arquivo resultante não pode ser lido diretamente num editor de textos ou por tecnologias que não sejam Python. (E, claro, o fato de se ler  e escrever tudo de uma vez impõe um limite prático de alguns milhares de registros).

Se optar por isso, é só manter todos os seus dados numa grande lista ou dicionário , e usar funções como essas:

```
import pickle

dados = {}

...

def salvar():
with open("dados.bin", "wb"):
    pickle.dump(arquivo, dados)

def carregar():
   global dados
   dados = pickle.load(open("dados.bin"))
```